# How to change to display:none after changing to block

Tags: javascript

Div is `display: none;`

When I click on link or image, I change to `display: block;` that's working fine.

When I click on that same icon or link, I want it to diappear.

So if link is active, Div is displayed, after that clicking back on link change display options.

Comment: Please post existing pertinent code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using**

```
<a href="#" id="toggleLink">Show</a>
```

you can do this:

***Plain JS***

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xjptp/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("toggleLink").onclick=function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("someDiv");
    var show = div.style.display;
    div.style.display = show=="none"?"block":"none";
    return false;
  }
  div.style.display="none"; // init
}
```

***jQuery:***

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c64hK/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#toggleLink").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#someDiv").toggle();
  });
});
```

If you want to toggle the text from Show to Hide, add this to the plain JS before return false

```
    this.innerHTML=div.style.display=="none"?"Show":"Hide";
```

and this to the jQuery

```
$(this).text($("#someDiv").is(":visible")?"Hide":"Show");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsfiddle showing a working concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/DjxM8/

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#showme").toggle();
});
```

jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function is probably what you want.

Comment: am not sure if jQuery is an option as it is not tagged. but +1 for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery you can do:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    if ($('div').css("display") == "block"){
        $('div').("display", "none");
    }
    else{
        $('div').("display", "block");
    }
});
```

**EDIT: for this particular case the toggle method is preferable. I recommend doing it my way if you ever wish to add more than 2 outcomes to an event, such as if you wanted to cycle through different background colours (lame example but serves the point)**

Comment: if using jQuery why not use `toggle`?

Comment: Yeah that's fine too(and obviously much shorter). This is just an alternative way.

Comment: Yup agreed, it works. But just that when a library function is available, it is better to make use of that. By the way, the down-vote was not mine so I can't do much about that.

Comment: I've added an additional detail as to why you might want to use my way (as it could handle more conditions if you needed more whereas toggle it seems can only handle 2.